# Sales Order fulfillment netsuite

Tags: netsuite

When I click and fulfill an order we Debit COGS ("cost of goods sold") and Credit Inventory. The issue is there was no shipment at this point. I run into a problem because when we click fulfill to print the pick ticket but the sale may occur in the next month.

Is there a way to configure the system so that the fulfill function does not record the COGS, but the COGS is recorded upon shipping? If not, what is the work around?

Comment: Sounds like you guys need to enable the pick, pack and ship functionality in NetSuite.  It is an addon module but it let's you separate the three distinct functions.

Comment: We do have that module enabled

Comment: You should be able to print the picking ticket from the sales order, without creating an item fulfillment.